# cast a pointer to a type in lldb

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, lldb

I want to debug a third-party c++ lib, is it possible to cast a pointer to a printable type?

I have tried

```
(lldb) expr static_cast<AGInfo*>(0x0000002fcdccc060)
```

but it shows an error of

```
error: cannot cast from type 'long' to pointer type 'mxnet::Imperative::AGInfo *'
```

Is there any way of doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

lldb uses clang for its expression parser, so it adheres pretty strictly to C++ with only a few modifications.  clang won't allow you to do what you were trying in source code:

```
 > cat foo.cpp
struct Something
{
  int first;
  int second;
};

int
main()
{
  Something mySomething = {10, 30};
  long ptr_val = (long) &mySomething;
  Something *some_ptr = static_cast<Something *>(ptr_val);
  return some_ptr->first;
}
 > clang++ -g -O0 -o foo foo.cpp
foo.cpp:12:25: error: cannot cast from type 'long' to pointer type 'Something *'
  Something *some_ptr = static_cast<Something *>(ptr_val);
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

So it won't work in lldb either.

Fortunately, C++ is less strict in C-style casts, so the same code but with:

```
  Something *some_ptr = (Something *) ptr_val;
```

compiles in actual source, and will work in the lldb expression parser.